# Is there any way to increase stack reserve size in running time in visual studio C++

Tags: c++, stack

I am developing an .exe solver in C++. There is a recursive algorithm in the solver, so I set the stack reserve size to be 2 100 000 000 in Configuration Properties->Linker->System->Stack Reserve Size. But when some customers run it on their machines, it crashes. It works fine on most of the machines. I reduce the stack reserve size to 0 and ask the customer to try it. It works. So I think the stack reserve size should be the problem.

Now I have two questions:

1. What is the potential problem of the customer's machine? I thought it is possible that the customer set a very small maximum size of virtual memory. So I try it on my machine, set the maximum size of virtual memory as 0 in Advanced system settings->Performance Settings->Advanced->Virtual memory->Customer size. But the solver does NOT crash in this case.
2. Is there any way to set the stack reserve size in the run time. If I can, then I can let the customer overwrite the stack size by ENV if the solver crash on his machine.

PS: Add more information. This code is compiled as 64-bit without setup LARGEADDRESSAWARE option (I don't know the default setting of this option). This code works almost very well on 64-bit machine. Indeed there is only one customer complains about the crash in the last several years.

Comment: If you are dealing with that much data, the fix isn't to increase your users stack size. It is to stop using recursion, declare memory on the heap if needed, and use an iterative method instead.

Comment: Do you know what the error is that the users are seeing?  Does that error message also suggest that the issue has to do with stack reserve size?  I just have a hard time believing that the stack reserve size is the problem.

Comment: You need to get ahold of a crash dump (minidump) which will tell you exactly where it's crashing (and thus hopefully *why*).

Comment: Thank you for the above answers! Indeed the crash happens when loading the solver. For testing purpose, I print out something to a file at the first line of the solver. But that file don't appear at all. That means the crashing is before running the first line of the solver.

Comment: @Feidao: You're right, the failure happens before any code runs in the process.  Not even library code can run without a main thread.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the stack size to 2GB is a ridiculous solution to this problem. The correct solution is to reduce the stack usage in the recursive algorithm, or use an iterative solution (possibly using a software stack to solve the "where do we go back to" issues that recursion solves for you).

One relatively easy solution, without knowing what the code actually does, would be to use `std::vector<T> v(size);` instead of `T v[size];` - this will make the size of `v` about 3 * size of pointer, instead of `sizeof(T) * size` on the stack - if you have a few larger arrays, this is really a useful way to reduce stack usage.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the crash is that the OS loader, while trying to set up the initial thread for the new process, failed to find 2.1GB of contiguous address space to allocate (reserve, not commit) for the thread stack.

This failure is non-deterministic, because Address Space Layout Randomization (a security feature) causes DLLs to load at random addresses, and this causes fragmentation of the address space.  Get lucky, and there's a fragment big enough for your thread stack.  Otherwise, instant crash before any of your code executes.

Changing the virtual memory settings doesn't matter, because the issue is address space, not maximum total virtual memory across all processes.

Based on your description, my crystal ball has revealed that:

- Your code is compiled as 32-bit with the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` option.
- Your code crashes consistently on computers running a 32-bit version of Windows.
- Your code sometimes works but often crashes during startup on computers running 64-bit Windows, or 32-bit Windows with the `/3GB` boot.ini option.

As Cyber said, you should architect your code to use a lot less stack space.  Mats has given some practical advice for doing this in his answer.

As far as setting stack reserve at runtime, yes it is possible, using the second argument of `CreateThread`.  Basically, you leave the main thread with a small stack (default size, for instance), then call `CreateThread` with the desired size and do everything from the new thread.  But don't do that, instead fix your ridiculously high stack usage.

Comment: Or, in a 32-bit memory model, it's probably completely impossible to find a 2GB memory region that is contiguous!

Comment: @MatsPetersson: With `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`, the 32-bit application's share of the address space can be up to 4GB - 64kB (because the zero page and a few nearby are still prohibited).

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The option for that is on the same property page as the Stack Reserve Size we already know he's set... given the symptoms it's 100% certain Large Address Aware has been enabled.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation! To answer your questions, I have added more information in the original post. I will try to reduce the stack size at first. I also ask the customer whether they run the solver on 32-bit machine and wait for the answer now...

Comment: @Feidao: The default for `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` (inside Visual Studio, the command-line defaults may differ) is enabled for 64-bit and disabled for 32-bit.  You should double check it (as I reminded Mats, it is on the same screen as the Stack Reserve Size).  I'm surprised that the problem occurs with a 64-bit build, since you should then several TB of available space.  Perhaps there are restrictions on the address of the initial thread's stack.  In any case, the explanation remains the same -- creation of the initial thread is failing due to lack of a large enough contiguous address block.